# ¿Cómo aplicar font en un pdf usando DOMPDF en CakePhp 3?

Tags: cakephp, dompdf

Estoy  usando el  framework cake PHP 3 y estoy generando un pdf usando la liberia  DOMPDF el problema que el pdf usa   un tipo de letra que no se como aplicarla,

Cabe mencionar que el pdf lo creo con html desde un controlador:

**

```
$html = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>
            <html lang='en'>
              <head>
                <meta charset='utf-8'>
                <style>
                 @font-face {
                   font-family: 'Soberana Titular Light';
                   src: url(\"http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/fonts/Elegance.ttf\") format(\"truetype\");
                 }
                </head>
              <body>
                  <div class='contenedor__bg'>
                    <div class='header'>
                      <div style='display: inline-block;width: 9.14cm;text-align: left;'>
                        <img src='img/img__logo--sep.png' style='height: 1.3cm;width: 4.37cm;'>
                      </div>
                      <div style='display: inline-block;width: 9.25cm;text-align: right;    float: right;'>
                        <img src='img/logo__dgb__350.png' style='width: 2.3cm;'>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style='width: 100%;text-align: center;padding: 0.1cm 0;'>
                      <div style='width: 100%;font-family: SoberanaSans-Ligh;font-size: 10pt;'>SISTEMA EDUCATIVO NACIONAL</div>
```

**

ya intente jalar una font desde internet , intente agregar la font en webroot/font y de ahi obtenerla pero nada me funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola quisiera responder mi propia pregunta por si alguien se encuentra  con el mismo problema que yo. Yo meti el css en el mismo html y para que interpretara la ruta de la font lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
 @font-face {
       font-family: 'SoberanaSans-Regular';
       src: url(".ROOT.DS.'webroot'.DS.'font'.DS.'SoberanaSans-Regular.ttf'.");
    }
```

La font la guarde en la siguiente ruta webroot/font/

Espero que sea de ayuda. Gracias!